# Integrating jsLint into BBEdit

Tags: javascript, node.js, applescript, jslint, bbedit

How do I incorporate jsLint into BBEdit?

- Environment:

  - OSX Mountain Lion
  - BBEdit *10.1.2 (3152)*

I installed [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (*0.8.14*) and ran

```
sudo npm install -g jslint
```

I am able to run **jslint** from the command line by running

```
jslint [filepath/]filename
```

---

I found a [tutorial](http://forrst.com/posts/JSLint_Script_for_BBEdit-UQV) that seems to explain how to connect **jsLint** to **BBEdit**; however, I have never written an AppleScript and have no idea where to start.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

---

### **UPDATE**

I loaded the [AppleScript](http://forrst.com/raw_code/c95ab22ac862655c91fbb8c0c35b65dfeebbdd88) from the tutorial into the AppleScript Editor Application and ran it.

I'm now getting the following error message:

> Can’t get paragraphs 3 thru -1 of "Can’t make POSIX path of missing
>   value into type Unicode text.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I am using the BBEdit FTP browser and working directly off the server. This was causing problems with the file path that the AppleScript was relying on.

A short-term solution is to work on the file locally and then upload it when complete.

The better solution would be to mount the server as a drive. This would provide the most functionality with the greatest ease of use.

Comment: I have started using the second 'better solution' listed above. I am using OSXFUSE and SSHFS to mount my server as a drive. This lets BBEdit access the files as if they were on the local machine. I then run the JSLint AppleScript.

Comment: It's worth noting that few scenarios would make working directly on remote files the 'best practice.'  A local development environment is the common pattern except when security demands that code not move from a given machine (which, is clearly *not* the case for you, since you're using a local IDE that is scriptable)